# Preview page/post revisions without overwriting current content

Tags: posts, pages, content, draft, review

Is it possible to add or update a Post/Page without it overwriting the current content that it on there?  I need to make some edits to a page, but I need to have someone review it before I can publish it and I don't want to overwrite the current content that is up there.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has built in [Revision Management](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management).

You can set the saved revisions to a custom number in the  wp-config.php file in your installation.

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 30 );
```

**NOTE:** You should be aware of the »autosave« mechanism, which also sets post revisions. So leaving a tab open for 1 hour with a Post Revision interval of 6minutes and a Revision limit of 10 revisions, might destroy your whole history.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**NOTE:** There's also the [Role »Contributer«](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor), which is *not* allowed to publish posts.

Comment: Great write up! The second and third blurbs have dropshadow and [sh*t](http://fuckinghomepage.com/)..!

Comment: @brasofilo Messed up the first one ... and I even got PS scripts for that! ;)

Comment: Suspected that... so many little apps, but then, hell, it's so easy and fast in PS :o)

Comment: But, sadly, you "can't" preview post revisions. You can compare the source code (nice, but ... not very useful), but there's no way to see the output :(. Unless you want to destroy the current and put invalid copy live on your site :(